# What is the benefit of TestFlightApp if I need to create a AdHoc distribution certificate and provisioning for all testers upfront?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, adhoc, testflight

After a few hours of reading I think to build for TestFlight I must go through the same old AdHoc distribution nightmares as usual. Set up various Certificates / Provisioning Profiles / Entitlements / etc., ask users for their UUID, register their devices, etc. etc. etc.

Then what is the benefit of TestFlight? What does it simplify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestFlight is primarily used (but only) for distribution of your app trough a simple and easy process by which you invite people so they can register their devices (hence, avoiding send emails with UDIDs, etc.), and receive emails with new updated builds and install with one click of a button. It also provides you an easy way to manage your builds and team members.

I don't know what I would have done with out it...

Comment: That seems great but I can't figure out how it works, and how to get started with it. I don't see how users can be invited by email and then automatically start beta testing. I still need to do a lot of manual things like register their UDIDs in iTunes connect. Or not?

Comment: TestFlight is easier for your testers to use. Lets you track who has installed what.  No certificates.  No entitlements. A single provisioning profile does the trick.

Comment: TestFlight will send you the UDID's  You put them in your provisioning profile.  Upload the build and that's it.

Comment: yes, you need to send them an invite through the site, then add their UDIDs to your provisioning profile - no way to get around that sadly. Then, just upload a build (with a distribution profile) and send to whomever you want from your team.

Comment: So how do I put those UDIDs in my provisioning profile? Is there a complete step by step guide?

Comment: when you add a user to your team, they get an email invitation to add their device, then you get an email that they registered their device and the UDID is in this email, so you just copy it to your device list on the apple developer site and add it to the appropriate provisioning profile.

Comment: You can add more devices by going to this link https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action, assuming you have already logged into developer.apple.com